# how to edit custom resource removing just one finalizer

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fabric8

I'm using fabric8 and java operator sdk.
I'd like to remove one custom finalizer in the `deleteResource` handler of the `ResourceController`. 
What is the suggested way to remove the finalizer and save the custom resource?

Comment: Hi, I'm from Fabric8 Kubernetes Client team. Could you please elaborate your question? I would appreciate some details on details of your custom resource and they way you would set finalizer using `kubectl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to add finalizers using Fabric8 Kubernetes Client. For example, if you want to add/remove finalizers like these in your Custom Resource's metadata:

```
  finalizers:
  - finalizer.stable.example.com
```

You can use either our typed API or typeless API for achieving this. I'm adding examples of both the approaches below using a [`Dummy`](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/crds/Dummy.java) Custom Resource provided in our [CRDExample](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/CRDExample.java#L121):

#### Typed API (Requires POJOs of Custom Resources)

```
MixedOperation<Dummy, DummyList, DoneableDummy, Resource<Dummy, DoneableDummy>> dummyCRClient = client
  .customResources(dummyCRD, Dummy.class, DummyList.class, DoneableDummy.class);
// Fetch resource fom Kubernetes API server
Dummy dummy2 = dummyCRClient.inNamespace("default").withName("second-dummy").get();
// Get metadata
ObjectMeta objectMeta = dummy2.getMetadata();
// Modify metadata
objectMeta.setFinalizers(Collections.singletonList("finalizer.stable.example.com"));
// Patch it back in Custom Resource
dummy2.setMetadata(objectMeta);

// Patch to Kubernetes
dummyCRClient.inNamespace("default").withName("second-dummy").patch(dummy2);
```

#### Typeless API (Provides way to access raw JSON Custom Resources)

```
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext crdContext = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext.Builder()
            .withGroup("demo.fabric8.io")
            .withPlural("dummies")
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .withVersion("v1")
            .withName("dummies.demo.fabric8.io")
            .build();
    // Fetch resource fom Kubernetes API server
    Map<String, Object> dummy2  = client.customResource(crdContext).get("default", "second-dummy");
    JSONObject dummy2JsonObj = new JSONObject(dummy2);
    // Get metadata
    JSONObject dummy2ObjectMeta = dummy2JsonObj.getJSONObject("metadata");
    // Modify metadata
    dummy2ObjectMeta.put("finalizers", new String[] { "finalizer.stable.example.com"});
    // Patch it back in Custom Resource
    dummy2JsonObj.put("metadata", dummy2ObjectMeta);

    // Patch to Kubernetes
    client.customResource(crdContext).edit("default", "second-dummy", dummy2JsonObj.toString());
}
```

Comment: excellent answer, thank you! already learnt it from your excellent blog. thank you!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :-)